# Connecting USB mouse to Galaxy SIII

Tags: usb, mouse

I bought a basic female to female USB adapter and connected my Galaxy SIII USB cable to the mouse. This didn't work. What am I doing wrong? Do I need an OTG cable? Something about USB hosts? I don't understand how to get this to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need an OTG cable. The pin layout is different than a regular micro USB to USB cable; essentially, it's equivalent to shorting pins 4 and 5 on a normal cable. This is what causes the phone to know that it needs to be the *host* rather than the *slave*.

In fact, you can [do this yourself](http://tech2.in.com/how-to/accessories/how-to-make-your-own-usb-otg-cable-for-an-android-smartphone/319982) if you're handy with electronics and have a cable you don't mind taking apart, though they're also readily available at many online retailers (Amazon, Newegg, Monoprice, etc).

Answer (score 1):

To connect any device to your Galaxy S3 (or any other host-capable Android device), you need a OTG host cable.  Without that host cable, the phone doesn't know it's supposed to act as the host rather than as a peripheral.

[This](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=108&cp_id=10833&cs_id=1083314&p_id=9724&seq=1&format=2) is an example of such a cable.  Most online retailers carry similar ones.